# gerrit install on existing git repository

Tags: git, gerrit

How can I install gerrit to git repository without copying the existing repo or move it or reinstall it? I can't do anything on the existing repositories because there are many projects(repos). I'd like to install gerrit to one(appropriate) git repo to try to review.
Thanks for any advices/corrections!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run Gerrit alongside your existing Git server. That is, your existing Git server and Gerrit can both serve Git repositories from the same directory.

This might be a good option, because you said you wanted to use Gerrit for one repository without moving or copying any repositories.

To do this, set the [gerrit.basePath](http://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-gerrit.html#gerrit.basePath) property in the Gerrit configuration to point at the directory containing your existing Git repositories before you start the Gerrit instance.

I've used this approach before when introducing Gerrit to a team, because it ensured that the team could revert back to using the existing Git server if they had any problems using Gerrit, thus avoiding any loss of productivity.